# Notation for a subspace of $H^1(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces, boundary-value-problem

In a work of mine, I need the following subspace of $H^1(\mathbb{R})$:
$$
\{u \in H^1(\mathbb{R}):u(0)=0\}.
$$
I first used the notation $H_0^1(\mathbb{R})$ for it but a referee did not like that because he says it refers to something else. Does anyone know the correct notation or have a suggestion as to what I could use?

Comment: Maybe $H^1_0(\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\})$?

Comment: $H^1_0(\Omega)$ means $u$ vanishes on $\partial\Omega$ for $\Omega=\mathbb R$ means it is goes to $0$ at infinity, which is different from $u(0)=0$.

Comment: Functions in $H^1$ are only defined up to null sets, so a condition like $u(0)=0$ does not make any sense. (It is the same for $L^p$ spaces)

Comment: @Tobius Functions in $H^1(\mathbb{R})$ have a continuous representative

Comment: @stange okay fair enough

Comment: kieranquared has the right answer, but why not give it a simple name like $V$ or $Z$

Comment: OK thank you. Yes, I agree, kieransquared has the right answer (thanks to @zwim, I understand why).

Comment: Then, @Umberto P. wins for the practicality and simplicity of his suggestion. Thanks to all who chipped in. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I would call it $\tilde{H}^1$

Comment: @LL3.14 Hey, that's a good idea!